# Retrieve a string between 2 same variables SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

I have a string something like this `1234-56-7-8-9012`. This can be any size and the values between the `-` can be any size. I need to extract the `7` in the middle of this string but cannot accommodate to the changing size of the string. This is what I've been using but it doesn't take the change of size:

```
@String = '1234-56-7-8-9012'

SUBSTRING(
        SUBSTRING(@String,CHARINDEX('-',@String)+1,LEN(@String))
        ,CHARINDEX('-'
            ,SUBSTRING(@String,CHARINDEX('-',@String)+1,LEN(@String))
        )+1
        ,1
    )
```

This will give me the 7 value, but sometimes that value will be 2 in length. Basically I need to get the number between the 2nd and 3rd `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @String varchar(50) = '1234-56-7-8-9012'

select substring(@String, charindex('-',@String,charindex('-',@String,1)+1)+1,
    charindex('-',@String,charindex('-',@String,charindex('-',@String,1)+1)+1)-
    charindex('-',@String,charindex('-',@String,1)+1)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
declare @String nvarchar(1000) = '1234-56-72-9012'
select 
    LEFT(y, CHARINDEX('-', y)-1)
from(
    select 
        RIGHT(x, LEN(x)-CHARINDEX('-', x)) y
    from(
        select RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String)-CHARINDEX('-', @String)) x
    )x1
)x2
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of using regular expressions because I think [SQL Server support them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx). All you need now is knowing how to find the number between the second and the third '-' via `regex`.

Comment: SQL Server does not support regular expressions out of the box. You have to compile some custom CLR functions into SQL Server in order to get regex functionality.

Comment: Thank you @Dan for information :) So are these CLR functions available for all ?

Comment: CLR functions are functions that you write yourself in a managed language such as C#, and then you compile them into SQL Server. But I believe you can find lots of CLR code by searching the Web, since it is a very common requirement to have CLR functions that can deal with regex.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e611c/2)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, 
                 CHARINDEX('-',@String,CHARINDEX('-',@String,1)+1)+1,
                 CHARINDEX('-',@String,CHARINDEX('-',@String,CHARINDEX('-',@String,1)+1)+1)- CHARINDEX('-',@String,CHARINDEX('-',@String,1)+1)-1);
```

Comment: Isn't he going to get an invalid object name from the use of dual? Unless I missed the part of his question which involves porting the solution to Oracle.

Comment: @Poldie yeah! Sorry, I got confused while copying the code from fiddle

Answer (score -1):

Try this... you can split a string between any character ('Z' here).

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (STRG VARCHAR (250)) 
INSERT INTO @A SELECT 'abcdZabcdefZabcdefghZabcdefghiZabccZaa';

WITH CTE(MOD_STR,STRG)
AS
(
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(250),SUBSTRING(STRG,1,CHARINDEX('Z',STRG)-1))
,CONVERT (VARCHAR(250),SUBSTRING(STRG,CHARINDEX('Z',STRG)+1,LEN(STRG)-CHARINDEX('Z',STRG))) FROM @A
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(250),MOD_STR +';'+SUBSTRING(STRG,1,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Z',STRG)>1 THEN CHARINDEX('Z',STRG)-1 ELSE LEN(STRG) END))
,CONVERT (VARCHAR(250),SUBSTRING(STRG,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Z',STRG)>1 THEN CHARINDEX('Z',STRG)+1 ELSE 0 END
,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Z',STRG)>1 THEN LEN(STRG)-CHARINDEX('Z',STRG) ELSE 0 END))
FROM CTE WHERE LEN(STRG)<>0
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE LEN(STRG)=0
```